# Django create a valid ModelForm with an incomplete Model to add fields manually after form validation

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

How do you create a post request to have a ModelForm be valid (giving you everything the user needs to fill out) but then alter the model (with everything the user shouldn't have to give you [such as username/profile, datetime, other computable variables, etc...]) before the form/formset is validated in the view?

Sample Code:

views.py

```
def view(request):
    # Create the formset, specifying the form and formset we want to use.
    LowerFormSet = formset_factory(LowerForm, formset=BaseLowerFormSet, extra=0)

    # If they are posting data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Grab the data they submitted
        formData = request.POST
        # highestForm = MealForm(formData, meal=meal, prefix='recipe')

        lower_formset = LowerFormSet(formData, prefix='lower_formset')

        lower_form in lower_formset:
            lower_form.instance.a = A.objects.create(…)

            # HERE
            # Each form isn't valid, because it is missing its associated higher object, despite not including the field in the ModelForm
            lower_form.save()
            # But if we create a foreign key/higher object and add it here, we are circumventing the  validation step, and creating objects when the validation might not be True
            lower_form.instance.higher = Higher.objects.create(…)
            lower_form.save()
            # How do you separate these concerns, so you can create a valid Model Form, then add the necessary parts after the validation?

        # Check for valid data
        if all([otherForm.is_valid(),
                lower_formset.is_valid(),
                other_formset.is_valid(),
                ]):
            # make the Higher here, and add it to each form
            for form in lower_formset:
                form.higher = higher
                form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('recipe:success'))
        else:
            return response = render(request, 'template', {…})
    else:
        # …
```

models.py

```
class Lower(models.Model):
    higher = models.ForeignKey(Higher, related_name="higher")
    # Etiher A or B is required, depending on information from the foreign key of the Higher
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, blank=True, null=True, related_name="switch_case")
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, blank=True, null=True, related_name="switch_case")
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def clean(self):
        if self.higher.a:
            if not self.a:
                raise AssertionError("The higher wants a, but you did not provide a")
            if self.b:
                raise AssertionError("The higher wants a, but you provided b")
        else:
            if not self.a:
                raise AssertionError("The higher wants b, but you provided a")
            if self.b:
                raise AssertionError("The higher wants b, but you did not provide b")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.clean()
        super(Lower, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're slightly confusing yourself by thinking about invalid forms. A form must always be valid before you do anything with it, but that doesn't mean it has to represent a valid instance of the model. What you need to do is to *exclude* the fields you don't want to show to the user, then set those on the instance afterwards.

```
class LowerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Lower
        exclude = ['higher']
```

and the view:

```
lower_formset = LowerFormSet(formData, prefix='lower_formset')

if lower_formset.is_valid():   # perform validation
    for lower_form in lower_formset:
        lower = lower_form.save(commit=False)  # create a Lower instance but don't save to db yet
        lower.higher = Higher.objects.create(…)
        lower.save()
```

Comment: somehow the Model's clean method is getting called during the full_clean of the formset, and that seems to be the complication, despite including the `excludes`

Comment: i think your logic is in the wrong place. Why is it in the model clean at all? But more importantly, how are you determining in the view what kind of HIgher you need? Can't you use that same logic in the form to determine whether you need an A or a B?

Comment: I put it in the model to ensure the correct one (not both). I check which type (A or B) for the Lower in view's POST (supported by the template providing the appropriate AForm or BForm). If I create a Higher object before the validation to supply to the Lower to make the Lower object valid, I am circumventing the validation.   If I wait for the validation, it appears the formset calls `_post_clean()` which in turn calls `full_clean()` which calls `clean()`. If the two (ModelForm and Model) are supposed to be as separate as you have suggested (and i have coded prior) then why the clean calls?

Comment: I put it in the model as well as I thought that db level validation should be considered when it is fully abstracted to the atomic level as possible (I am already using a modified GFK structure with relation_type related tables).